# why can't I get handlebars to loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to copy as much as I can from the documentation, though I'm working with handlebars.js in a rails app with backbone.

I have a collection taken right from the handlebars examples.

```
var list = { people: [
    {name: "Alan"}, 
    {name: "Allison"}, 
    {name: "Ryan"}
  ], group: "Bloggers" };
```

I pass this collection to handlebars as

```
    if(list.people.length >0){
            var showList = HandlebarsTemplates['htmlList'](list);
            console.log(showList);
        $('div#holdList').html(showList);
        }

    },
```

in my hbr file, I have

```
<ul>
this gets output
    {{#each list.people}}
    this doesn't, but should. <br/gt;

    {{/each}}
</ul>
```

My output shows the 'this gets output', but I can't get handlebars to enter the loop and show 'this doesn't but should.'

what am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should iterate over people and not list.people in your template.

Comment: thanks ProTom, I can't tell you how many different iterations of that I had tried, never thought to drop the parent.